# Implicit Key for a one-to-many relationship in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an aggregate class that will contain a collection of another class, but that class will only ever exist in a collection on that aggregate, so I have no need for an ID on it in my code, or a need for a reference to the aggregate. For example:

```
public class SalesListing 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LocalizedDescription> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedDescription
{
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to just declare the key for the `LocalizedDescription` class as a combination of `SalesListingId` and `CultureCode` without creating a `SalesListingId` property or reference back to `SalesListing`. Any way to do this with EF 5.0 ?

For example, here's an example how I'd imagine such an API would look like if it exists:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocalizedDescription>().BelongsTo<SalesListing>(s => s.Description)
            .WithKey((s, ld) => new { s.Id, ld.CultureCode })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will still need to specify an ID

Answer (score 0):

You can define composite keys using the following syntax:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocDesc>().HasKey(ld => new { ld.CultureCode, ld.Title });
```

That said, I think you will regret not defining an integer primary key. If you ever need to export the contents (such as for an external review or translation), matching records by ID will be faster and less error prone than matching by title. Having the ID doesn't hurt and is easier to include now than to retrofit later.

I think you can specify the FK mapping implicitly by not supplying a specific property for the relation in the mapping definition:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesListing>().HasMany( e => e.Descriptions ).WithRequired();
```

Should you need to specify the foreign key property, introduce a `SalesListingID` property for the value and use the following mapping instead:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesListing>().HasMany( e => e.Descriptions ).WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey( r => r.SalesListingID );
```

Comment: "That said, I think you will regret not defining an integer primary key" - I know, thus I want tell it "hey, LocalizedDescriptions belong to SalesListing, so make a key based on SalesListingId and CultureCode" but I am trying to be purist here and not clutter my objects with RMDB specifics.

Comment: Yeah the simple `.WithRequired()` doesn't work - it demands a foreign key